# CoreMIDI app not showing in other software

Tags: swift, macos, midi, coremidi

I am playing around a bit with CoreMIDI in Swift on OSX, and got most of the things to work properly.

The only issue I have now is that my app is not seen by other software and apps and an available input/output. This is the case for in GarageBand, MIDIMonitor and the VVMidi test apps.

I tried multiple things, including this which seems to be the correct approach :

```
let clientCreateResult = MIDIClientCreate("MIDIApp", { (notification, _) -> Void in
        print("Configuration Changed")
    }, nil, &midiClient)
if (clientCreateResult != noErr) {
    printError(clientCreateResult)
    return;
}

let inputCreateResult = MIDIInputPortCreateWithBlock(midiClient, "MIDIApp In", &inputPort, MyMIDIReadBlock)
if (inputCreateResult != noErr) {
    printError(inputCreateResult)
    return;
}
let outputCreateResult = MIDIOutputPortCreate(midiClient, "MIDIAPP Out", &outputPort)
if (outputCreateResult != noErr) {
    printError(inputCreateResult)
    return;
}
```

Sadly no luck. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I tried reproducing the exact same code as existing frameworks with no significant result.

I could really use some pointers as of why my app isn't listed in other ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a virtual destination. See the docs for `MIDIDestinationCreateWithBlock`

Comment: That makes your app appear as an input in other apps. Use `MIDISourceCreate` if you want your app to also be an output that other apps can connect to. [More details in this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572747/why-doesnt-this-simple-coremidi-program-produce-midi-output?rq=1).

Comment: True. I wasn't exactly sure what the OP wanted. Your linked answer is more complete.

Comment: Well, I can't believe I missed that... It works just great, I was sure I tried this, I guess I messed up the code and just moved on. Thank you so much!